# How can I deploy an app using legacy peer deps?

Tags: google-app-engine, npm, dependencies, npm-install, dependency-management

So I have two packages in my project with conflicting peer dependency. One of the deps is only supporting react^16.14.0.

So I managed to get it to work locally by using `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`, but how can I use this command when I deploy my project to Google Cloud App Engine? App Engine install fails with  `Could not resolve dependency.`

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade your node version? Also could you share your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me, I got this working by creating `.npmrc` in the root of my project. And adding `legacy-peer-deps=true` in the file. [Source](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241076152)

Comment: the source link is not working. Could you show how you did it?

Comment: @LuisQuiroga create a .npmrc file in the root directory, and add the following line: legacy-peer-deps  or legacy-peer-deps=true

Comment: This worked for me. Cheers. I had issues with dep conflicts for the ```@testing-library/react-hooks```

Answer (score 1):

So, the reply from @keyur Shah worked for me.

Except I did only enter legacy-peer-deps in the .npmrc file located in the root of the project. ( instead of legacy-peer-deps=true )

the link he mentions ias source is: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241076152